# Prevent icon inside disabled button from triggering click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out proper way to make a click event not fire on the icon of a disabled link.  The problem is when you click the Icon, it triggers the click event.  I need the selector to include child objects(I think) so that clicking them triggers the event whenever the link is enabled, but it needs to exclude the children when the parent is disabled.

**Links get disabled attribute set dynamically AFTER page load.  That's why I'm using .on**

Demo here:**(New link, forgot to set link to disabled)**

http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/9/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn" disabled>
                <i class="icon-file"></i>
                Test
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</diV>​

$('.btn').on('click', ':not([disabled])', function () { alert("test"); });​
```

**Update:**
I feel like I'm not using .on right, because it doesn't take the $('.btn') into account, only searching child events.  So I find myself doing things like `$('someParentElement').on` or `$('body').on`, one being more difficult to maintain because it assumes the elements appear in a certain context(someone moves the link and now the javascript breaks) and the second method I *think* is inefficient.

Here is a second example that works properly in both enabled/disabled scenarios, but I feel like having to first select the parent element is really bad, because the event will break if someone rearranges the page layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/32/

Comment: Why do you use event delegation here?

Comment: Because elements may become disabled at anytime.  For example, we have links/buttons which become disabled for a few seconds when clicked.  So I want the click handler to not fire while buttons/input[submit]/links are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use event delegation if you only want to listen for clicks on the `.btn` element itself:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() { 
    if (!this.hasAttribute("disabled"))
        alert("test");
});​
```

If you'd use event delegation, the button would need to be the matching element:

```
$(someParent).on('click', '.btn:not([disabled])', function(e) {
    alert('test!!');
});​
```

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/68/)

Or use a true `button`, which can really be disabled:

```
<button class="btn" [disabled]><span class="file-icon" /> Test</button>
```

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/35/), [disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/36/).

Here, no click event will fire at all when disabled, because it's a proper form element instead of a simple anchor. Just use

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() { 
    if (!this.disabled) // check actually not needed
        this.diabled = true;
    var that = this;
    // async action:
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.disabled = false;
    }, 1000);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi, but on my team there are a lot of links being used in this way.  Getting them to use proper html semantics is a separate battle, and even if won, it'd be awhile before they are all weeded out.

Comment: Then your only way is to check for the disabled attribute in the handler (manually). You can't use event delegation on the button (or whatever) itself, to use that feature you'd need to listen on a parent element for `.btn:not([disabled])`

Comment: I'm going with the first option for now, but encouraging the use of buttons instead of links where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
.on('click', ':not([disabled])'
```

^ This means that, since the icon is a child of the button `".btn"`, and it is not disabled, the function will execute.

Either disable the icon, also, or apply the event listener only to the `<a>` tag that is your button, or use `e.stopPropagation();`

<strike>I would suggest using `e.stopPropagation();`, this should prevent the icon from responding to the click.</strike>

That doesn't seem to work for me ^

[Disabling the icon](http://jsfiddle.net/YLKN7/), however, does.

Comment: How would you suggest "apply the event listener only to the <a>".  This is what I came up with for desired behavior, but seems a poor design because moving the link breaks the event: http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/32/

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the selector properly.

```
$('.btn').not('[disabled]').on('click', function () { 
    alert("test"); 
});​
```

[See it live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ytj/34/)

**Edit:**

```
$('.container').on('click', '.btn:not([disabled])', function () { 
    alert("test"); 
});​
```

Comment: disabled is not a class here.. If it was a class then it is trivial.. It is an attribute

Comment: I need the disabled to be part of the .on event so that it doesn't fire if dynamically changed to disabled.  With this, I can disabled the button, but the click event still fires.

Comment: Don't see a reason why it couldn't be a class. There's no href, so it appears 'disabled' is only being used for the style. Selecting with 'disabled' as an attribute is also fairly trivial, thanks for the edit Alexander. Sushanth your answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to add the event using delegation here as you are trying to base the event based on the attributes of the element.

You can add a check condition to see if you want to run the code or not.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    if( $(this).attr('disabled') !== 'disabled'){
        alert('test!!');
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/f5Ytj/38/)**

Comment: It wasn't me, but I don't see a reason for event delegation *and* manually checking the attribute in the handler

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Basically something like the following should work

```
$('.icon-file').on('click', function(event){event.stopPropagation();});
```

You may want to add some logic to only stop bubbling the event when the button ist disabled.

**Update:**

not sure, but this selector should work:

```
$('.btn:disabled .icon-file')
```